# Is it possible to keep a subscription running even app is closed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sockets, ionic4

For background purposes I made a deep search in ionic documentation (native and no native), and in other pages, and found that may be there is a posibility to achieve this (keep running a subscription even the app was closed), but I can't understand at all where I should put one thing or other thing to make BakckgroundMode plugin working... (I think this plugin is not working in my device), but it's hard to inspect that thing because you can't inspect your device if it's in background mode with chrome://inspect...

This is the BackgroundMode plugin:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

I have installed backgroundMode 0.7.2 which isn't the most actualized plugin, but trying to install the latest gives me errors on build, so i tried this version and works.

In the docs, I see the following:

> The plugin creates the object cordova.plugins.backgroundMode and is
>   accessible after the deviceready event has been fired.

So in order to run background mode, in my page.ts inside constructor (later I will talk about why in the constructor), I put:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', ()=> {

      this.backgroundMode.enable();
      this.backgroundMode.setDefaults(
        {
          title: 'executing in bg mode...',
          text: 'background mode was activated successfully!',
          color: '#fff',
          resume: true,
          silent: false
        }
      );

      this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();

      this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(()=>{

         this.isAcceptedObservable = this.localNotifications.on('yes').subscribe(res =>{

            console.log('confirmed!');
            this.backgroundMode.unlock();

         });

         //And more observables...

      });

});
```

the subscriptions inside backgroundMode.on('activate') subscription are the things that I need to keep running even if app is closed.

the reason of why I was put that code in constructor is because I'm using also ngx-socket-io to listen to emit and broadcast functions of a socket server in node that i created, so one of the subscriptions that is linked to socket events is:

```
this.getInvitationSubscriber = this.getInvitation().subscribe(data =>{

     this.invitations.push(data);
     this.showNotification({
          title: 'Invitation received!',
          text: 'Someone invited you!',
          icon: data['from']['avatar_src'],
          attachments: [data['from']['invitation_src']]
     });

     console.log(this.invitations);

});
```

in ionViewWillEnter i call:

```
ionViewWillEnter{

     this.socket.connect();

}
```

and this function is outside the constructor:

```
  getInvitation(){

    let observable = new Observable(observer =>{

      this.socket.on('subject', data =>{

        observer.next(data);

      });

    });

    return observable;

  }
```

I'm expecting to keep running the 'notifications listener' that I have in constructor inside the backgroundMode.on('activate') function to receive notifications even app is closed, but I dont know if it's possible with ngx-socket-io and the structure that i have.

also I have injected background mode in app.module providers and in otherpage.module.ts provider and imported correctly so that's not the error, but I'm not getting notifications...

I know that notifications scheduling are correct because if i simple try not to use backgroundMode and putting that subscriptions outside backgroundMode.on('activate') subscription, i'm getting again notifications, but only works if app is in foreground or in suspended...